# Why doesn't jQuery document ready function run in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My first time to use jquery

I added this script into my code

Here is my test.aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="myProj.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href="css/wordcloud.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var
                words = $('#tagi text'),
                l = words.length,
                current = null,
                delay = 2000;

            function clearBlink(o) {
                var
                    ca = o.getAttribute('class').split(' '),
                    i = ca.indexOf('blink');

                if (i !== -1) {
                    ca.splice(i, 1);
                    o.setAttribute('class', ca.join(' '));
                }
            }

            function addBlink(o) {
                var
                    ca = o.getAttribute('class').split(' ');
                ca.push('blink');
                o.setAttribute('class', ca.join(' '));
            }

            function wordblink() {

                var e;

                if (current !== null) {
                    clearBlink(words.eq(current)[0])
                }

                current = Math.floor(Math.random() * l);
                e = words.eq(current);
                addBlink(e[0]);

                setTimeout(wordblink, delay);
            }
            
            alert("Hello");
            wordblink();

        });

    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <svg id="tagi" x="0px" y="0px" width="920px" height="324px" viewBox="0 0 920 324">
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 497.4292 293.7129)" class="st17 st0">SALES</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 727.8999 191.9316)" class="st17 st20">CPC</text>
                <text id="XMLID_2_" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 433.0854 82.7407)" class="st17 st8">LEADS</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 188.187 144.3555)" class="st5 st17 st22">CLICKS</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 380.8301 145.1353)" class="st17 st29">ADWORDS</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 378.8799 54.6626)" class="st5 st28 st6">BING</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 247.0718 191.1514)" class="st5 st28 st18">YANDEX</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 129.9268)" class="st5 st28 st30">vKONTAKTE</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 250.9712 76.1118)" class="st5 st28 st14">REMARKETING</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 229.9131 169.5225)" class="st5 st28 st25">MARKETING</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 472.4722 105.3691)" class="st5 st28 st27">LOOKALIKE</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 735.7007 163.4639)" class="st5 st28 st1">BIG DATA</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 128.9111 264.4697)" class="st5 st28 st26">REKLAMA EFEKTYWNOŚšCIOWA</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 191.3057 102.2393)" class="st5 st28 st24">PERFORMANCE</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 318.4351 289.0342)" class="st5 st28 st1">AUTOMATION</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 740.77 211.4307)" class="st5 st28 st21">ATTRIBUTION</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 683.0542 230.5381)" class="st5 st28 st19">BEHAVIORAL</text>
                <text transform="matrix(0.9244 0 0 1 632.7485 97.0288)" class="st5 st28 st16">E-COMMERCE</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 663.5552 139.2856)" class="st5 st28 st3">KONWERSJE</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 251.3608 240.4502)" class="st5 st17 st31">SHOPPING CAMPAIGNS</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 217.0439 54.2744)" class="st5 st28 st11">PRODUCT FEED</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 119.9526 240.2871)" class="st5 st28 st13">TRACKING</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 444.0044 34.7744)" class="st5 st17 st4">KEYWORDS</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 125.4019 129.147)" class="st5 st28 st15">CTR</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 350.8022 207.5303)" class="st17 st2">REVENUE</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 81.5249 212.6006)" class="st17 st9">ROI</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 545.0063 316.7061)" class="st5 st28 st23">COSTS</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 638.2075 66.7529)" class="st5 st28 st12">AD GROUPS</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 185.8467 282.4043)" class="st5 st28 st10">OPTIMIZATION</text>
                <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 34.1494 150.5947)" class="st5 st28 st7">TARGETING</text>
            </svg>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page it does not work.

I put alert  but it never got executed

I wonder what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do you include `jQuery` into your code?

Comment: I am not seeing jquery loaded in your code above. have you added jquery library in master page or anywhere? also, what console error are you getting in browser developers console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like nowhere in your code contains a `<script>` tag that includes the jQuery library into the page, so the browser doesn't understand what `$(document).ready` means. jQuery is an external library and not part of JavaScript by default, so you must include it manually.

You need a tag like the following ([source](https://code.jquery.com/)) to include the jQuery library on the page:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then your code should execute, as long as the library is being included before your script. A good place to put the above tag would be inside the `<head>` tag of your HTML, before your own `<script>` tag. This should ensure the library is loaded before your script runs.

Comment: Thanks, it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see where you imported the JQUERY library or linked to the JQUERY CDN, try to link to the CDN. you can find it here `https://code.jquery.com/`

Answer (score 2):

it seems you forgot to define the `<script>` for using jQuery. you might try to attach jQuery CDN

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

copy the CDN above link in the html you made. for reference: https://code.jquery.com/